# Отслеживание изменений в файле

Tags: c#

Вы замечали, что если изменить открытый в Visual Studio файл извне, то наша любимая IDE тут же это "заметит" и выдаст запрос на перезагрузку файла для актуализации отображаемого контента? Как работает этот механизм отслеживания "на лету"? Как его реализовать на C# в своей программе?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @maxwell, ого, вот это оперативно, спасибо. Оформите как ответ? Или просто закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого используется класс [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx), который, согласно MSDN:

> Ожидает уведомления файловой системы об изменениях и инициирует
> события при изменениях каталога или файла в каталоге.

[Руководство по использованию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ch2s8yd7(v%3dvs.90))